# Find in Europe, someone tasting almonds

Tags: treasure-hunt

Q: **Find in Europe, someone tasting almonds.**

Can you help me in figuring out what the answer to the question possibly could be? Unfortunately, I don't have any clues with me.

Comment: Is this from an ongoing competition of some sort?

Comment: This is a question from some treasure hunt asked 5-6 years ago.

Comment: @SreenathPG Please tell me, you have not tried 5 or 6 years to solve this 8-]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you take the first letter of each word, you get `FIESTA`.

Fiesta is Spanish for "party".

I'm not really sure what answer you're looking for, but it might be just 'Fiesta'.